# Change default C compiler output

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to change the default `a.out` to something nicer, like `file.c` automatically becomes `file`?

I know one can do this with `gcc file.c -o file`, but... is there something easier?

Comment: @Charles, was just using my newfound ability to make tags :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Although if you have `make` available, you can just do:

```
make file
```

Comment: @tekknolagi: Yes, without a makefile.

Comment: Can I change the default compiler from `cc` to `gcc`?

Comment: @tekknolagi: Yes, do `export CC=gcc`.  But note that `cc` and `gcc` are usually the same thing.

Comment: @tekknolagi: Yes, without a makefile, because Make has a set of default actions. They cover C compilation. GNU Make will display them when invoked `make -p`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth just realized i forgot to accept... accepted!

Comment: Actually, it is possible! But it requires some careful editing of GCC's 'specs' (see `gcc -dumpspecs`) and doing it your way is probably easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dirty, but you could write a shell script to automatically append the -o filename.

Comment: Tis true; I wrote an alias for my `.bashrc` that was `cmpp file` routed to `gcc file.c -o file` and it was lovely, but annoying that I had to write it.